# Я обучался в Университете/университете Герцена

Tags: орфография

Как правильно?

> Я обучался в Университете/университете Герцена.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно:

*Я обучался **в Университете Герцена.***

**[Розенталь, пункт 6 и 7](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=20#pp20)**

В названиях научных учреждений и учебных заведений **первое слово** (и все имена собственные) пишется с прописной буквы.

С прописной буквы пишется начальное слово **неполного** названия, которое употребляется в функции полного.

**Из Википедии**

**С 1 января 2015 года** полное официальное наименование — Федеральное государственное бюджетное образовательное учреждение высшего образования **«Российский государственный педагогический университет им. А. И. Герцена».**

Университет назван в честь русского писателя, политика и философа **Александра Ивановича Герцена**. Российский государственный педагогический университет им. а и. Герцена ведет отсчет своей истории **с 13 (2) мая 1797 года.** Именно в этот день Петербургский Воспитательный дом по распоряжению императора Павла I стал самостоятельным учреждением и взят под покровительство императрицы Марии Федоровны.

[Отзыв](https://tabiturient.ru/vuzu/herzen/)